# Storing RDF data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, rdf, nosql

I saw some questions about use of Cassandra to store RDF data but they are really old (2013).
So, I have RDF time annotated data (RDFStream) and I'd like to store them in a Cassandra cluster. I know that probably it's not the best idea but I have research interest. 
I'm looking for a way to do it because I'm not sure this is really possible. For now I'm really confused on how organise db.
Someone has experience or any hint about that? Is it possibile to do?